# Little result using RCF theorem and an inequality by Vasile Cirtoaje

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, alternative-proof, jensen-inequality, convexity-inequality

Well , I want to share with you a little result :

> The function
> $$f(x)=(x)^{2(1-x)}$$ is concave on $I=[\frac{1}{2},1]$

Moreover Vasile Cirtoaje proved that :
$$f(x)+f(1-x)\leq 1\tag{1}$$

So we can apply the [RCF theorem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1029-242X-2011-101) since $1-x+x=2\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ and with $(1)$ it implies that :

> Let $1>x_1>0,1>x_2>0$ be two real numbers such that $x_1+x_2\geq 1$ then we have :
> $$f(x_1)+f(x_2)\leq 2 f\Big(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\Big)\quad (E)$$

Well my question :

Have you an alternative proof ?

Thanks in advance !

### Update:

If $x_1,x_2\in[0,5,1]$ then we can directly apply Jensen's inequality .Well it's a first important remark . For the second case $x_1,x_2\in(0,1]$ we can perhaps use Bernoulli's inequality , take logarithm on both side and then use derivatives .If you have a nice idea make a comments/answers . I recall that my question concern the proof of $(E)$ .

Reference : [1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1029-242X-2011-101) Vasile Cirtoaje, "Proofs of three open inequalities with power-exponential functions",
The Journal of Nonlinear Sciences and its Applications (2011), Volume: 4, Issue: 2, page 130-137.
https://eudml.org/doc/223938